# AutoCompleteTextView populated by remote API gives exception IndexOutOfBoundsException OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, web-services, api, indexoutofboundsexception, autocompletetextview

So i wanted to implement an dynamic AutoCompleteTextView which, which will give the list that is to be populated in the dropDown of the AutoCompleteTextView.

Below are the files and the code that i have written.

```
addLocationEdit = (AutoCompleteTextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.add_locations_list_edit);

    addLocationEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            new ForLocations().execute(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    addLocationEdit.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "LOCATIONS LIST SIZE: " + locationList.size());

            list.add(new AddLocationsBean(locationList.get(position).getId(), locationList.get(position).getName(), locationList.get(position).getDistrict(), locationList.get(position).getState()));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            addLocationEdit.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Below is the AsyncTask that im using:

```
class ForLocations extends AsyncTask<CharSequence, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        locationList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(CharSequence... params) {

        try {

            CharSequence param = params[0];

            URL url = new URL(Api.LOCATION_URL + "q=" + param);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            inputStream = conn.getErrorStream();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            }

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 1000);
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            locationResponse = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("LOCATION ERROR: ", "LOCATION ERROR: " + e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        try {

            // PARSE JSON

            locationAdapter = new LocationAutoCompleteAdapter(MainActivity.this, locationList);
            addLocationEdit.setAdapter(locationAdapter);
            locationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the adapter i'm using:

```
public class LocationAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocationBean> {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<LocationBean> suggestions, list, tempList;

InputStream inputStream;
StringBuilder stringBuilder;
String locationResponse;

Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        String str = ((LocationBean) resultValue).getName();
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            suggestions.clear();
            for (LocationBean locationBean : tempList) {
                if (locationBean.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) || locationBean.getState().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) || locationBean.getDistrict().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    suggestions.add(locationBean);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        List<LocationBean> filterList = (ArrayList<LocationBean>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (LocationBean locationBean : filterList) {
                add(locationBean);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
};

public LocationAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LocationBean> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    tempList = new ArrayList<LocationBean>(list); // this makes the difference.
    suggestions = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();
}

@Override
public LocationBean getItem(int position) {
    return tempList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tempList.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autcom_name);
        holder.state = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autcom_state);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (list.get(position).getState().isEmpty()) {
        holder.state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.state.setText(list.get(position).getState());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView name, state;
}}
```

When i click on the list item im getting the below error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: varun.com.dynamicautocompletetextview,
>   PID: 27492
>       ava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>       at varun.com.dynamicautocompletetextview.MainActivity$3.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:110)
>       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:906)
>       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.-wrap1(AutoCompleteTextView.java)
>       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1202)
>       at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Its an **IndexOutOfBoundsException** that occurs when i click the list item.

Please suggest what can be the cause and the also the solution to this.

Feel free to suggest any new way to implement AutoCompleteTextView population via a web service/API call.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
The data is being populated in the AutoCompleteTextView. Ive logged and checked and i can see the data itself in the dropDown.

Comment: The AutoCompleteTextView might not have been populated with data or failed to populate. You may be trying to access an array with no elements at all.

Do a pre-check if the data is being returned or not. If it is being returned, check if the data is being set or not. This Exceptions usually is occuring because you are trying to access an array that has no item or outside its bounds.

Comment: @SumanAdhikari i can see the dropDown in the AutoCompleteTextView, but when i click it it gives me null. The data is being populated clearly.

Comment: Did you debug and see?

Comment: @Vivek_Neel yess i did. the list is being filled, but onItemClick the list size is 0

Comment: May be , When onItemClick is called , you have to perform your async task and add the responses to your list and then get the elements from your list.

Comment: i solved it. you can look at my answer given below

Comment: checkout https://github.com/mobisystech/autocompleteview which is easy-to-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found the solution and here it goes.

1. Don't override `getItem` and `getCount` (if you are using `ArrayAdapter`).
2. Instead of using `list.get(position)` use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`
3. As below:

```
LocationBean bean = (LocationBean) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
list.add(new AddLocationsBean(bean.getId(), bean.getName(), bean.getDistrict(), bean.getState()));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
addLocationEdit.setText("");
```

Thank you.